# Suppress command output being ignored

Tags: bash

There's an issue I am facing with the following command.

Output does not seem to be suppressed, and I keep getting 100s of lines printed to the terminal.

```
#!/bin/sh

n=0
until [[ $n -ge 1000 ]]
do
   /usr/ud/runupdate $1 &>/dev/null && break
   n=$[$n+1]
   sleep 2
done
```

Are there any other things I can do to suppress output?

Comment: `&>` is a bash-ism. Use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it then it sounds like `runupdate` isn't playing nice. It may be opening up `/dev/tty` or `/dev/console` directly rather than writing to stdout/stderr. Bad behavior, and not much you can do about it if that's what it's doing.

Comment: Switched it... doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: Also, try `n=$((n+1))`.

Comment: @Roadowl, or `((n+=1))`

Comment: When `runupdate` is running, can you check the output of `ls -l /proc/$(pgrep runupdate)/fd`

Comment: @methuselah : You don't have, by chance, the source code of _runupdate_, do you?

Comment: Unfortunately, not - its a vendor application

Comment: Try piping it to `cat` to see if its behavior changes when it's in a pipe: `/usr/ud/runupdate "$1" | cat &> /dev/null`